# Normal baking not working

Tags: texture-baking, normals, normal-map

I'm trying to bake the normal from high poly to a low poly model. I made a cage that perfectly fits outside the high poly but when baking I get weird artifacts that don't look like a ray distance problem (see screenshot).

The baking texture is set to noncolor, ive tried with 32bit as well and there are no intersections. The strange thing is that only a part of my model gets these artifacts, the rest is fine.

I separated the part of the model that doesn't bake correctly so maybe someone can help me understand what i did wrong (the shared file has the same settings I used to bake).

[image]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your object?

Comment: hi, yes I'm trying to upload it rn but my connection is slow

Comment: Here it is, it was slow cause of the packed bake that was too big, so i removed the image (if u want to recreate it I used 4k non-color 32bit) [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=n7y85zWO" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/n7y85zWO/)

Comment: Try to bake without cage. If it helps, recreate the cage.

Comment: I already tried both those things and the problem was still there, but thanks for the help!

Comment: actually not having the cage gets rid of those kind of artifacts but produces others (green ones, look like a ray distance problem because my model has both big shapes and small details, so a cage is definitely needed imo because adjusting the ray distance value never gets rid of the green artifacts completely)

Comment: It looks like your cage is too big, it must hit unwanted surfaces. I can't put my finger on where exactly, but if I duplicate your low-poly and fatten it only a bit it will have a much better result